# Please help me with solving this error - "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Tags: angular

Here is the code :

let teamsId: string[] = [];
teamsId = params['ids'].split(',');

This code was working fine with my local machine but on server I am getting above error.

Comment: Where `params` variable is coming from?

Comment: through routing parameter

Comment: Could you please include the code here?

Comment: your params object doesn't have 'ids' property

Comment: this.trackedSubscriptions.push(this.route.params.subscribe(params => {

      let teamsId: string[] = [];
      teamsId = params['ids'].split(",");